# how to get price for hour PHP

Tags: php, function, time, return

I have to do an exercise in which if a car has been parked for 1 hour or less it must pay $ 50 and if an hour passes it should be $ 100 (the double) and so on.

```
function a(){
$time = 10; // x time

$hour = 50;
echo "price for hour: " . $hour;

if ($time < 60) {

    $time_parked = $hour;
    return $time_parked;

} elseif ($time > 60 && $time < 120) {

    $time_parked = $hour * 2;
    return $time_parked;

}

echo "Amount to pay: " . $time_parked;
```

the time is received in minutes

Comment: this isn't valid php. What issues are you having?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the following single formula to calculate the parking fee:

```
function getFee($time) {
    return (floor($time / 60) + 1) * 50;
}

echo getFee(50). "\n";     // 50
echo getFee(110). "\n";    // 100
echo getFee(120);          // 150
```

### Demo